# Context Dictionary isn't being passed with render in view

Tags: django-templates, django-views

Alright, I've been poking around the internet for a solution to that there's something obvious that I'm missing but so far no good.

I'm currently having trouble with passing a context dictionary to a template in Django via my view. So far everything else seems to return, except for the dictionary that I'm passing to the template.

```
def search_subjects(request):
"""
This is our search view, at present it collects queries relating to:
    - Subject ID
    - Study Name
    - Date Range Start
    - Date Range Start
Then validates these entries, after which it redirects to the search
results view.
:param request:
:return: Redirect to search results if search button is pressed and form fields
are valid or renders this view again if this request is not POST
"""

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SearchForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        search_dict = {}
        search = form.save(commit=False)
        search.subject_search = request.POST['subject_search']
        search.study_search = request.POST['subject_search']
        if request.POST['date_range_alpha'] and \
                dateparse.parse_datetime(request.POST['date_range_alpha']):

            search.date_range_alpha = request.POST['date_ranch_alpha']
        else:
            search.date_range_alpha = EPOCH_TIME
        if request.POST['date_range_omega'] and \
                dateparse.parse_datetime(request.POST['date_range_omega']):
            with_tz = dateparse.parse_datetime(request.POST['date_range_omega'])
            search.date_range_omega = with_tz
        else:
            search.date_range_omega = timezone.now()

        search.save()

        for k, v in form.data.items():
            search_dict[k] = v
        print(search_dict)
        return render(request, 'dicoms/search_results.html', search_dict)
else:
    form = SearchForm()

return render(request, 'dicoms/search.html', {'form': form})
```

And my template here:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Search Results</title>
</head>
<body>
Here's what you searched for:
<div>{{ search_dict }}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The page that I'm getting back:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Search Results</title>
</head>
<body>
Here's what you searched for:
<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

What on earth am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I walked away from this for a bit and managed to solve it. I wasn't passing a context dictionary correctly. Fix can be seen below.:

```
            search.save()
            context = {'search': search}
            return render(request, 'dicoms/search_results.html', context)
```

Adjusting the template accordingly:

```
Here's what you searched for:
<div>{{ search.subject_search }}</div>
<div>{{ search.study_search }}</div>
<div>{{ search.date_range_alpha }}</div>
<div>{{ search.date_range_omega }}</div>
```

Results in:

```
Here's what you searched for:
<div>herp </div>
<div>herp </div>
<div>Jan. 1, 1970, midnight</div>
<div>Feb. 26, 2019, 11:05 p.m.</div>
```

Had I trusted in django and simply passed the whole search object in the beginning I wouldn't have ended up here. But you live and learn.